# Trying to establish InternalNetwork connection between UbuntuServer 14.04 and UbuntuClient 16.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, server, dhcp

I have installed two VMs, problem is the client not getting the internet connection at all.

1. **UbuntuServer 14.04** which should be as a Host for the client Ubuntu

   Server has two adapters:

   1-st one is simple NAT connection to get internet from main machine

   2-st one is InternalNetwork named "testnet"

**UbuntuServer** also had installed **squid** (squid is setted up right atleast I think so) on it and **dhcp** to setup IPs for clients by automatic.

Here is the the settings on my **UbuntuServer**:

For the `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

    #NAT Connection
    auto eth0
     iface eth0 inet dhcp

    #Internal Network
    auto eth1
     iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

And settings for **DHCP**:

```
subnet 10.0.2.15 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.100.20 192.168.100.100;
option domain-name servers 192.168.100.5, 8.8.8.8;
option routers 192.168.100.1;
option broadcast-address 10.0.2.255;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;}
```

subnet and gateway was taken from `ifconfig` input for `eth0`

As for the **Ubuntu 16.04** client everithing was untouched except the VB network setting it was setted up according to InternalNetwork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure NAT at your Ubuntu 14.04 server.
Enable forwarding:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Make forwarding persistent. Open file:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

and add the line to the file:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Install iptables:

```
sudo apt-get install iptables
```

Enable NAT:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Make iptables rules persistent. Run

```
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

Afterwards open file:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and add to the file this line:

```
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules
```